# Assets not displayed in AIR application (but files exist in installation folder!)

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

Here is my problem:

I'm building an AIR package, using the mxmlc and adt command line tools.
I run the following command in a /bin/stagging directory

```
mxmlc +configname=air -compiler.library-path+=..\..\my_project\libs\,
      ..\..\Modeles\libs,..\..\Service\libs,..\..\sflexlib\libs
      -define+=CONFIG::appMode,"'staging'" ..\..\my_project\src\my_project.mxml
      -o my_project.swf
```

So I create a file called my_project.swf including all the libs I need and the mxml application is the my_project.mxml file.
A my_project.swf file is created but I cannot test it at that moment because it is an AIR application. So I launch this command:

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "..\..\certificat.p12" 
    -storepass "mypass" my_project.air my_project-app.xml my_project.swf 
    -C ..\..\my_project\src\assets\ .
```

If I understood the adt command, this should create an .air package described by the my_project-app.xml file and including the my_project.swf file and assets directory. I install the app and launch it but no pictures are displayed... I look in the installation folder and there is an assets folder containing all the pictures :(

If I launch the app directly via the FlashBuilder IDE, the pictures are well displayed.

Has anybody a solution to that? As said, the pictures are correctly extracted from the package and installed but not displayed... The paths are correct too =(

Thank you in advance

Comment: IF you want to distribute the images w/ the SWF; dont' you have to embed them into the swf using the embed metadata tag?

Comment: In the source code, I have Embed tag and buy launching the app via FBuilder, I have the images but if I run the command given above, and running adl, I don't have any

Comment: Here is the CSS file: http://pastebin.com/pJdxmAjr

The .authentification class gives the background-image property with the Embed keyword
the .logo class defines a background too.
I wonder if I have to precise in the mxmlc command that this is my css file but don't know how to do that...

Comment: And here is the MXML code that defines the classes: http://pastebin.com/b7vLicUH

Comment: I've never been able to get embedding to work properly in CSS.  Instead I use url like you are doing for the font file.

Comment: Ok, I'll look for that more deeply. I'm a trainee and got this code, so I'll study it once again :D But the fact is that FBuilder builds the swf perfectly, contrary to the mxmlc command... Mmmmmh I'll study that and give you news.
thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The halo theme was not included in the compilation line!

So I added it and launched that command:

```
mxmlc +configname=air -compiler.library-path+=..\..\my_project\libs\,
  ..\..\Modeles\libs,..\..\Service\libs,..\..\sflexlib\libs
  -define+=CONFIG::appMode,"'staging'" -theme+="%FLEX45_FRAMEWORK%"\themes\Halo\halo.swc
  ..\..\my_project\src\my_project.mxml -o my_project.swf
```

`%FLEX45_FRAMEWORK%` is the `FLEX_4.5_PATH\frameworks` directory

I found the solution when I got an error by changing Embed to url() in the css file. Before that it was only a warning! =)

Thank you guys!